# How to enable the TLS Inspection and IDPS premium features of Azure Firewall Policy

Tags: azure, firewall, terraform-provider-azure

I have created an Azure Firewall Policy with Premium tier using the following terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy" "firewall_policy" {
  name                     = var.firewall_policy_name
  resource_group_name      = var.rg_name
  location                 = var.location
  sku                      = "Premium"
  threat_intelligence_mode = "Alert"
  #idps_mode               = "Alert"
  #tls_inspection_mode     = "Alert"
}
```

I want to enable the **TLS Inspection** and **IDPS** premium features of Azure Firewall Policy using the terraform. For that I have followed the official [azurerm_firewall_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall_policy) documentation. But this document doesn’t contain the Arguments Reference of TLS Inspection and IDPS features of Azure Firewall Policy.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As provided in this ***[`Microsoft Documentiation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/premium-deploy)*** ***[`ARM template`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.network/azurefirewall-premium/azuredeploy.json)*** , you will have to declare the ***TLS inspection*** and ***IDPS*** in `azurerm_firewall_policy` in ***tls_certificate*** block and ***intrusion_detection*** block .

***ARM Template:***

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/firewallPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
            "name": "DemoFirewallPolicy",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'DemoIdentity')]": {}
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', variables('keyVaultName'), variables('keyVaultCASecretName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', 'DemoIdentity')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "tier": "Premium"
                },
                "transportSecurity": {
                    "certificateAuthority": {
                        "name": "[variables('keyVaultCASecretName')]",
                        "keyVaultSecretId": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('keyVaultName')), '2019-09-01').vaultUri, 'secrets/', variables('keyVaultCASecretName'), '/')]"
                    }
                },
                "intrusionDetection": {
                    "mode": "Alert",
                    "configuration": {
                        "signatureOverrides": [
                            {
                                "id": "[parameters('sigOverrideParam1')]",
                                "mode": "Deny"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "[parameters('sigOverrideParam2')]",
                                "mode": "Alert"
                            }
                        ],
                        "bypassTrafficSettings": [
                            {
                                "name": "SecretBypass",
                                "protocol": "TCP",
                                "sourceAddresses": [
                                    "*"
                                ],
                                "destinationAddresses": [
                                    "1.1.1.1"
                                ],
                                "destinationPorts": [
                                    "80"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

***So the above in terraform will be something like below :***

```
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = "example"
  location            = "West Europe"
  identity {
      type = "UserAssigned"
      user_assigned_identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.test.id]
  }
  sku="Premium"
  tls_certificate{
      key_vault_secret_id = azurerm_key_vault_secret.Certificate.id//<id of the keyvault Secret where CA is stored>
      name = //<name of the certificate stored in the keyvault>
  }
  intrusion_detection {
      mode="Alert"
      signature_overrides {
          id = "sigOverrideParam1 id (2024897)" 
          state = "Deny" 
      }
      signature_overrides {
          id = "sigOverrideParam2 id (2024898)"
          state = "Alert"
      }
      traffic_bypass {
          name = "SecretBypass"
          protocol ="TCP"
          source_addresses = ["*"]
          destination_addresses =["1.1.1.1"]
          destination_ports = ["80"]
      }
  }
}
```

***Reference :***

***[Terraform `azurerm_firewall_policy` Arguments Reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/firewall_policy#arguments-reference)***